# Dynamic Memory in C

Tags: c

I can't understand what doing the row

`*(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1) = n;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSTR 100

int main() 
  {
    int i, j, k, n;
    char str[MAXSTR];
    printf("Enter amount of rows: ");
    fgets(str, MAXSTR, stdin);
    k = atoi(str);
    int* sizes = (int * ) calloc(k, sizeof(int));
    int* sum = (int * ) calloc(k, sizeof(int));
    int** m = (int ** ) calloc(k, sizeof(int * ));
    printf("Enter matrix:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) 
        {
          fgets(str, MAXSTR, stdin);
          char* sym = str;
          while (1) 
             {
               m[i] = (int * ) realloc(m[i], (++sizes[i]) * sizeof(int));
               n = strtol(sym, & sym, 10);
               sum[i] += n;
               if (n) 
                  {
                  *(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1) = n;
                  } 
               else 
                  {
                   --sizes[i];
                   break;
                  }
           }
       }

   printf("\nMatrix: \n");
   for (i = 0; i < k; i++) 
      {
        for (j = 0; j < sizes[i]; j++)
        printf("%i ", *(m[i] + j));
        printf("\n");
      }
    printf("\nSum of elements of row:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
      printf("#%i - %i\n", i + 1, sum[i]);

    free(sizes);
    free(sum);
    free(m);

    return 0;
```

Comment: There's **a lot** of things that are incorrect in the code you've posted.... I'm unsure where to start.

Comment: First, please format your code such that indentation matches the nesting level of your C code. Second, don't use short, cryptic variable names like `i`, `j`, `k` and `n` - please give them **descriptive names** so that we can easily see what their purpose is.

Comment: C does not require you to put all of your variable-declarations at the start of a function (it hasn't done since C89 went out of fashion) - consider relocating the declarations to where they're first-used so you don't have uninitialized variables polluting the local scope.

Comment: Don't use `#define` for constants, use `const int name`. Also, you need to verify that `calloc` succeeded by checking every return-value is `!= NULL`. You need to inspect the return-value from every function call you make (`printf` returns a negative `int` on failure, `fgets` returns `NULL` on failure; You _probably_ shouldn't be using `realloc`. Avoid using `++` and `--` when the sequence-points are not clear.

Comment: Also make sure you free your `m[i]` arrays.

Comment: @Dai Using `#define` for constants is just fine in C, and there is no need to check `printf` return value.

Comment: @qrdl Yeah, I'll admit checking `printf` is overkill. However `const int` should still be preferred over `#define` imo. Also, when printing non-formatting strings `puts` should be preferred over `printf` to help prevent the risk of unsanitized user-supplied input being used as a `printf` format string.

Comment: @Dai There are situations when you cannot use `const`, for example in `case`, for static var initialisation, or as a dimension for static/global array, and event in case of local non-static array it is a subject to VLA support (optional since C11). Therefore in many cases `define` is better then `const`, so it is not a good idea to push `const` on newbies.

Comment: @qrdl I stand corrected :) (I could _swear_ that static `const` in C was somehow equivalent to `constexpr` - but I checked the specs after you pointed it out and I admit that I was very wrong...  though do any C compilers allow `constexpr` as an extension?)

Comment: @Dai Even if some compilers do, I wouldn't rely on this, very non-standard (for C) feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m` is the matrix. Or more formally, it appears to be an array of "rows".  Where each row is an array of integers.

`sizes[i]` is the length of the row represented by `m[i]`.

This expression

```
*(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1) = n;
```

Appears to assign the value `n` to the last index of the row identified by `m[i]`.  Essentially, it's appending to the end of the reallocated array.

This entire block of code is a bit complex:

```
      while (1) 
         {
           m[i] = (int * ) realloc(m[i], (++sizes[i]) * sizeof(int));
           n = strtol(sym, & sym, 10);
           sum[i] += n;
           if (n) 
              {
              *(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1) = n;
              } 
           else 
              {
               --sizes[i];
               break;
              }
       }
```

It could be simplified to just:

```
int rowsize = 0;
while (1)
{
    n = strtol(sym, &sym, 10);   // parse the next number in str
    if (n == 0)                  // the row ends when 0 is read
    {
       break;
    } 
    m[i] = (int *)realloc(m[i], (rowsize+1) * sizeof(int);  // grow the row's size by 1
    m[i][rowsize] = n;
    sum[i] += n;
    rowsize++;
}
sizes[i] = rowsize;
```

Comment: @John_Vatson - if you found the answer useful, don't forget to upvote it and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question the statement `*(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1) = n;` assigns the value `n` to whatever `m[i] + sizes[i] - 1` points to. `m` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, so `m[i]` is an address of an int pointer.  `sizes[i] - 1` is usually how you convert from a size to index, so it's an offset from that int pointer.

Here are some suggested changes (all but one implemented below):

1. Reduce variable scope but initialize `sum` to `NULL` before the first failure so it can be unconditionally deallocated
2. It is better user experience to just read the data and terminate with an empty line instead of asking for the user count upfront.  Just update the count `k` as we go along.  This eliminates `atoi` which does not do any error handling.  If you want to crash the program due to being out of memory you have to provide the data not just large a count.
3. (not fixed) `realloc` of 1 element at a time, if the `O(i^2)` is a performance issue, keep track of `size` and `capacity` of `sum`.  When `size == capacity`, `realloc` by some factor, say, `2`.  Optionally, `realloc` to `size` when when we finish reading data as we now have the actual number of lines `k`.
4. No point of printing the array you just entered, which means we can get rid of the `m` and `sizes` arrays
5. Deallocate sum if `realloc` fails by introducing a temporary `sum2` variable that will be NULL on error, but `sum` will still point to previously allocated data
6. Check for under and overflow of `n` and `sum`
7. Use `sizeof` on variable instead of type so you can change type just one place if needed
8. Allow 0 values by passing in by using a separate pointer `endptr` than `sym` to `strtol()`

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHECK(p, msg) if(!(p)) {\
    printf("%s:%d %s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, (msg));\
    goto out;\
}
#define MAXSTR 100

int main() {
    int k;
    char str[MAXSTR];
    int *sum = NULL;
    printf("Enter matrix:\n");
    for(int i = 0;; i++) {
        fgets(str, MAXSTR, stdin);
        char *sym = str;
        int *sum2 = realloc(sum, (i + 1) * sizeof(*sum));
        CHECK(sum2, "realloc failed");
        sum = sum2;
        int j;
        for(j = 0;; j++) {
            char *endptr;
            long n = strtol(sym, &endptr, 10);
            CHECK(n >= INT_MIN && n <= INT_MAX,\
                "value truncated");
            if(sym == endptr) {
                break;
            }
            sym = endptr;
            CHECK((n >= 0 && sum[i] <= INT_MAX - n) || \
                (n < 0 && sum[i] >= INT_MIN - n),\
                "sum truncated");
            sum[i] += n;
        }
        if(!j) {
            k = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Sum of elements of row:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("#%i - %i\n", i + 1, sum[i]);

out:
    free(sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Example execution:

```
Enter matrix:
0 1 2

Sum of elements of row:
#1 - 3
```

Answer (score 0):

- `m[i]` is a pointer to the first element in the *i*:th matrix row
- `sizes[i]` is the current number of columns in row *i*
- `sizes[i] - 1` is the last element in row *i*
- `m[i] + sizes[i] - 1` is a pointer to the last element in row *i*
- `*(m[i] + sizes[i] - 1)` is the last element in row *i*

When allocating memory in C the result should not be cast, so

```
int* sizes = (int * ) calloc(k, sizeof(int));
```

should be simply

```
int* sizes = calloc(k, sizeof(int));
```

Also, the rows of the matrix *m* are never freed; to free the entire matrix you would need

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    free(m[i]);
}
free(m);
```